# opencv: how to efficiently convert a std vector of 2D Mat into a 3D Mat

Tags: opencv, vector, multidimensional-array, 2d, mat

With `std::vector<cv::Mat> matList` with several 2D Mat in that vector, one has to access the pixel values in the third dimension by using, e.g., `matList.at(k).at<float>(i, j)`. Instead, i'd like to have a 3D mat, (`mat3D`) so that I would access that same pixel using `mat3D.at<float>(i, j, k)`. k can be equal to up to several hundreds. The rows and columns are typically above 2000. What would be the most efficient way(s) to make this conversion, apart from assigning each pixel explicitly from the vector of 2D Mat objects to this 3D Mat object?

Comment: You want to acces RGB value of each pixel?

Comment: I'm dealing with 1-channel images (gray scale). So, ```mat3D.at<float>(i, j, k)``` would give me the intensity value of that grayscaled pixel. 
Each 2D Mat object is originally defined as ```Mat(rows, cols, CV_32F)```.

Comment: You need to copy values to the 3D mat anyway. However, There no such great support for 3D matrices in OpenCV. You may want to use Eigen instead. As a shortcut, you can have a template function that wraps your call, something like: `template <typename T> T at(vector<cv::Mat>& vm, int i, int j, int k) {return vm[k].at<T>(i,j);}`

Comment: @Miki I was hoping that there would be a faster way to copy the data to make that 3D Mat, e.g, using the pointer to each k-th data array, since opencv provide the Mat::data or Mat::ptr().

Comment: No, there isn't. A `Mat` won't wrap a `vector<Mat>`, so you need to copy anyway.